# How to put a subquery within an aggregate subquery

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL-Server 2000 and am trying to find duplicates with certain conditions.  Someone here helped me earlier with the duplicate part which was great, however, I can't figure out how to filter the duplicated cases further.
I need to move the "where" statement to the subquery so that I *only* get contractor duplicated names as opposed to all duplicated names which is what's happening with this code (the code is first finding all duplicates and then filtering out the contractors and I'd like it to do the opposite).  The problem is that I'm mixing it into an aggregate statement and it's giving me an error.  I tried to put in another subquery within the subquery but it still gave me an error.
Any help is appreciated.  Here's a simpler (I'm learning) version of the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c1.contactid) as 'ContactID', c1.lastname as 'Last Name', c1.firstname as 'First Name'
FROM contacts c1 INNER JOIN (SELECT lastname, firstname FROM contacts group by lastname, firstname     
HAVING count(*)>1)
dups on c1.lastname=dups.lastname and c1.firstname=dups.firstname
WHERE (c1.contractor=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select C.contactid As ContactID
    , C.LastName As [Last Name]
    , C.FirstName As [First Name]
From contacts C
       Inner Join   (
                   Select C1.LastName, C1.FirstName
                   From contacts As C1
                   Where C1.contractor = 1
                   Group By C1.LastName, C1.FirstName
                   Having Count(*) > 1
                   ) As dups
         On C.LastName = dups.LastName
            And C.FirstName = dups.FirstName
Where C.contractor = 1
```

You are going to need the filter on `contractor = 1` in both the subquery and the outer query. Otherwise, you might return people that happen to have the same name as a contractor and are duplicated.

Also, you do not need the `Distinct` keyword if ContactId is the primary key of the Contacts table.

Comment: I think this is the safest since I may add to the filters.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the example code you have given, placing the where clause between the "from contacts" and "group by lastname, firstname" should do they trick.

Comment: Thank you--so simple and I couldn't get it until your comment.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
contact.ContactId,
contact.FirstName,
contact.LastName
FROM contacts as contact
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT ContactID FROM contacts GROUP BY FirstName, LastName HAVING Count(*) > 1
) AS Dups
ON Dups.ContactId = contact.ContactId
WHERE
contact.isContractor = 1
```

you are very close. this will provide you a list of each individual record that has a matching record with the same first name and last name. Hope this helps

Comment: quick question! if one record is marked contractor, but another is not, do you still want it in the record set? or do you only want duplicates that are both contractors?

Answer (score 0):

Move the where clause to the subquery. It fill first filter out all non-contractors, and then group the remainder.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c1.ContactId
   ,c1.lastname as 'Last Name'
   ,c1.firstname as 'First Name'
  from contacts c1
   inner join (select lastname, firstname
                from contacts
                where c1.contractor = 1
                group by lastname, firstname
                having count(*) > 1) dups
    on c1.lastname = dups.lastname
     and c1.firstname = dups.firstname
```

Oh, and unless there's a really good reason, you really don't want to include embedded spaces in your column aliases ("Last Name", "First Name").